# What exactly 'this' means in AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, angularjs-controller

**index.html**

```
 <body ng-controller="StoreController as s">
  <h1 ng-click="s.changeValFunc()">{{s.carname}}</h1>
  <h2>{{s.carname}}</h2>
  </body>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);
app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.carname = "Volvo";
    this.changeValFunc = function(){
        this.carname="BMW";
    }
});
```

Clicking on h1 tag changes {{carname}} for both h1 and h2 to BMW. Isn't it "this" refers to the current element being clicked. Am confused on how controller properties are shared among views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 2):

The controller function is instantiated with `new`. That means it works like this:

```
function StoreController() {
    this.carname = "Volvo";
    this.changeValFunc = function () {
        this.carname="BMW";
    }
};

var s = new StoreController();

console.log(s.carname); // Volvo
```

The `s` in your view is a reference to the instantiated `StoreController`, which has those attributes, because you put them there in the constructor function. You might want to see [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/476) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Post was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In your case this refer to the controller itself.

So any attribute in that controller can be accessed with

```
this.attribute
```

In your case you "assign" the controller to a parent element

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as s">
```

This mean that you create an instance of **StoreController** for the element body.

Changing the attribute **carname** you change it for the entire controller.

If you know littlebit of OO programming you can see the controller as a Class and with this you refer the instance of the class.

This is true for your case, in javascript **this** has some strange behaviour sometimes.

As said by deceze you can take a look at some posts that explain how **this** works in JS.

hope this helps

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks. Just that in OO programming we say new on constructor that belongs to a class. Here we have just the function. Where does class fit in here?

Comment: @mustafa Javascript doesn't have classes, it only has objects and functions. "Class" behaviour is realised with the behaviour of the `this` and `new` keywords and `prototype`. It's just as "OO" as class based OO, arguably even more so, since *everything* is an object. This is not the appropriate place to expand on that though, there is more than enough discussion about this already.

Comment: Yeah, now I know what to search for regarding this.